# How to make nested json from json string

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller

I am tring to create nested json string here is my json string below,

```
[  
   {  
      'CompanyID':'1',
      'Name':'Company1',
      'DepartmentName':'Executive General and Administration',
      'ModifiedDate':'2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',

   },
   {  
      'CompanyID':'2',
      'Name':'Company2',
      'DepartmentName':'Executive General and Administration',
      'ModifiedDate':'2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',

   },
   {  
      'CompanyID':'3',
      'Name':'Company3',
      'DepartmentName':'Executive General and Administration',
      'ModifiedDate':'2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',

   }
]
```

and i want result like this

```
[  
   {  
      'CompanyID':'1',
      'Name':'Company1',
       department":{
            'DepartmentName': 'Dpt1'
       }
    }
]
```

I want company wise department for this json string... I used Jarray but failed to do so...

my code:

```
string jsonCompany = "[{'CompanyID' : '1','Name' : 'Company1','DepartmentName' : 'D1','ModifiedDate' : '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',},{'CompanyID' : '2','Name' : 'Company2','DepartmentName' : 'D2','ModifiedDate' : '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',},{'CompanyID' : '1','Name' : 'Company3','DepartmentName' : 'D3','ModifiedDate' : '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',}]";

string jsonDept = "[{'DepartmentID' : '91','Name' : 'Executive84','GroupName' : 'Executive General and Administration','ModifiedDate' : '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',},{'DepartmentID' : '92','Name' : 'Executive85','GroupName' : 'Executive General and Administration','ModifiedDate' : '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',},{'DepartmentID' : '93','Name' : 'Executive86','GroupName' : 'Executive General and Administration','ModifiedDate' : '2005-06-01 00:00:00.000',}]";

object dynJsonCmp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonCompany);

dynamic dynJsonDept = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonDept);
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Could you describe "company wise department"? What is the actual problem?

Comment: you know there is an extra `,` at the end of each right? just letting you know

Comment: actually i want nested json like company wise department list... Its a single department in my json string but it will result in nested json

Comment: how is this related to MVC? is it send to or from a controller?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane:  no

Comment: do you generate the json? or do you download it from somewhere and try to parse it?

Comment: Why did you add the `jsonDept` string into your question?  It's not the expected output of your transformation, so why did you show it?  Also, where does the `'DepartmentName': 'Dpt1'` value come from?  `Dpt1` doesn't show up anywhere in your input strings.

Answer (score 2):

One of the cleanest ways of such manipulation is with using classes. 
Based on the json you initially provided, and your initial question, you can do the following.:

```
class Company
{

    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public object Modify => new {
        CompanyID, Name, department = new { DepartmentName }
    };

}
```

Then you can simply deserialize into a list, convert it with the help of `Linq` and serialize it

```
var modifiedList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Company>>(jsonCompany).Select(c => c.Modify);
string updatedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modifiedList);
```

Since your code seems to show a different json, you may have to modify the Linq part according to what you are actually trying to do. You can look into Linq to check what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I think you've managed to actually understand what the question is!

Comment: well in the latest edit, the first two blocks made it quite clear. Yet as many including me have mentioned, the third is still contradictory