# ASP.NET WebAPI: is a dedicated resource for a type containing only a subset of properties (from another one, another resource) a good practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

Let's say I have 2 Dtos as follows both from User an Entity Framework entity:

```
public class UserDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; } 
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}

public class ResourceDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

That are respectively say used in two different controllers:

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    // GET: /Users/Get
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class ResourcesController : ApiController
{
    // GET: /Resources/Get
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

It's a very simplified example to illustrate what I am struggling with right now. I feel it's a bit overkill to return dtos from a resource with plenty of unused properties.

Is it a good habit to return dtos with a smaller set of properties that reflect another dto / entity (and hence create a dedicated controller for the matter)? Or is it better to parametrized the get in one single controller in order to return a different type (the latter does not sound much rest to me...).

Comment: Are you wanting to follow REST? If so, you return the resources as they are; or use a query to limit the returned properties. Creating two options of the same resource isn't REST and will cause chaos long-term. As a service, you don't know what parts of a resource your consumers require hence limiting properties on the service-side makes no sense. A well-known exception is the back-end for front-end principle (different topic); they typically don't follow REST.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst technically speaking they are not the same "resource". 
So basically according to you it's generally fine to filter the properties to return using options?

Comment: yes, you can use parameters to filter which fields to return. it is even more or less common practice. you can find articles like [this](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_fields.htm). Otherwise you might want to read about [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/learn/)

Comment: @PavelAgarkov thanks I was actually thinking about GraphQL... but wanted to stick to traditional REST didnt know option for filtering was that common, I thought I was about to commit a sin doing so. I guess that if tableau is doing it that must be okay.
Thanks again!

Comment: is the `ResourceDto` just to return a smaller set of properties

Comment: @NevilleNazerane yup but got my answer from Pavel, it seems legit to add options on the get just to filter out undesirables properties, as I said I thought it was bad (and preferable to have another controller just for the sake of having another type). My bad.

Comment: Ok. But consider using something like the class I have created here as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296892/991609. That way you can have your business logic in the same class and you don't repeat all properties each time. Although it does come with it's pros and cons