# LINQ-TO-JSON cannot get value in array

Tags: c#, json, linq

I am trying to get values with LINQ-TO-JSON in this JSON-TREE, So far it looks good until i've approached this **categories** element.

I want to get the value "**Teknik**" from this value and this is what i've tried to far without success.

```
  Name = json["items"][i]["categories"].Children().Value<string>() ?? "Not assigned"

  Name = json["items"][i]["categories"][0].Value<string>() ?? "Not assigned"

  Name = json["items"][i]["categories"].First.Value<string>()
```

[image: Here is the image of the tree]

But none of these results works for me. Please help!

Comment: I haven't heard about "LINQ-TO-JSON" nor does Googling return anything in the first page. JSON.NET supoprts LINQ queries. *This* though isn't a LINQ query

Comment: Post the actual code, input string, what you expected and what you got. If you use a library like JSON.NET mention it in the question *and* the tags

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) is part of Json.NET.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to share a sample of JSON that reproduces the problem **as text**?  On stackoverflow we ask that you include your code, error messages, exception details and data (JSON, XML, etc) as text, not as an image.  For why, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3744182) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/3744182).

Comment: @dbc which means this is a JSON.NET question. LINQ is one of the query APIs of JSON.NET, not something special. And the code here isn't a LINQ query

Comment: you also have options to convert json into objects. Check this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48296892/991609

Comment: @Kerpalito the example code in [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) looks a lot like what you are trying to do - access the categories array of an RSS channel's items. One solution uses indexers, the other LINQ queries. Neither solution looks like what you posted here.

Comment: @NevilleNazerane that's what the OP already did. This is a question about JSON.NET too

Comment: @Kerpalito you have to post an actual json sample otherwise people won't be able to help you. The documentation example works. What's different in your case? Why didn't you use similar code?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos well the OP has done it in a dynamic way. serializing using newsoft will help him get a strongly typed object that he can then use Linq on too

Comment: @NevilleNazerane this *is* JSON.NET. You *can* work with LINQ against a JObject and there's a [suspiciously similar](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) example in the docs. Changing access techniques will probably change one coding issue for another

Comment: true... you can. which is why i mentioned "you also have the option". since you had already mentioned json.net.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the actual JSON string and the "tree" doesn't help. The JSON string in [Querying JSON with LINQ](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) could be represented with a similar tree, so I'll assume that's your source data:

```
string json = @"{
  'channel': {
    'title': 'James Newton-King',
    'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com',
    'description': 'James Newton-King\'s blog.',
    'item': [
      {
        'title': 'Json.NET 1.3 + New license + Now on CodePlex',
        'description': 'Annoucing the release of Json.NET 1.3, the MIT license and the source on CodePlex',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'CodePlex'
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'LINQ to JSON beta',
        'description': 'Annoucing LINQ to JSON',
        'link': 'http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx',
        'categories': [
          'Json.NET',
          'LINQ'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}";

JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
```

The example shows two ways to access values, through indexers or LINQ queries.

Using indexers, you'd only need `[0]` to access the first category of an item, eg:

```
rss["items"][i]["categories"][0];
```

That returns a JValue object as a JObject. You can cast it directly to `string` to get its value, eg:

```
(string)rss["items"][i]["categories"][0]
```

Or to a JValue, if you want to handle it as a JSON object and read the Value property, eg:

```
(rss["items"][i]["categories"][0] as JValue).Value;
```

A LINQ query wouldn't need indexers. If you wanted to retrieve the Category names you could write :

```
var query= from item in rss["channel"]["item"]
           from category in item["categories"]
           select new {Name=(string)category};
```

Or

```
var query = from category in rss["channel"]["item"].SelectMany(item=>item["categories"])
            select new {Name=(string)category};
```

Or

```
var query = rss["channel"]["item"].SelectMany(item=>item["categories"])
                                  .Select(category=>new {Name=(string)category});
```